# Setting Permissions to a group/User in Django

Tags: django, django-permissions

I've a group in `auth_group` table. I need to set permissions to a group. There are set of permissions in `auth_permission` table. Now If I need to map all the permissions to a group, do I need to add different rows for each permissions, or can it be done by adding all the permissions as a string of 1 & 0?

For eg:- Should I add entries in the table as

`id,group_id,permission_id`

```
1,1,1
2,1,2
3,1,3
4,1,4
```

or is there any way, I can add all the permissions in one string, such as `1234`, each digit signifying a permission_id?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get all permissions from `Permission` model and add them to a group:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission

permissions = Permission.objects.all()
auth_group = Group.objects.get(...)
auth_group.permissions.add(*permissions)
```

Comment: Thanks. But how will that be represented in mysql tables? As in, the structure that I mentioned above- table-like or a string wise?

Comment: @user2935897 all permissions ids will be added to table auth_group_permissions (id,group_id,permission_id)